# Loading of windows form takes more time that usual?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created a windows form application in c# having two forms.
2nd form loads on click of each button on form1. I have six buttons on first form.2nd form contains textbox whose content is assigned at runtime. Now if I click on more than 3 buttons one after other the form is hanged nothing happen.Also for second click form2 takes tim to load. I am not getting the reason behind this. I have used following code for show hide.
`{this.Hide();} to hide and  {this.ShowDialog();}`to open form2.

Comment: Can you post some source code ?

Comment: You should show the code, otherwise it's hard to find out why it's taking long to load. Also, what @harshit said

Comment: @ harshit: thanks for advice. I was unaware about that.

Comment: private void SettingsClose_Click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        { this.Hide();}                                                                private void showHideFlyout()
        { this.ShowDialog(); }   This is the code I have used to show and hide form 2.

Answer (score 0):

The dialogboxes are two types.

Model and Model less.

When you open other form through showdialog, we have to finish the work with that dialogbox then only we can able to go back.

The second form you can load by calling form2.Show()